# How do I get around "Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons"?

Tags: php, uploads, media, security

I was wondering how I could allow .tiff files to be uploaded in my wordpress site. I get the message "Sorry this file type is not permitted for security reasons".

This question has been asked in other places, but the solutions suggested aren't working for me.

I have tried using the following snippet in my theme's functions.php file, I saw a lot of suggestions to use this or something similar to extend the allowed file types:

```
function my_wonderful_mime_types($mime_types){
    $mime_types['tiff'] = 'image/tiff'; // Adding an extension, I tried 'tif' too
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_wonderful_mime_types', 1, 1);
```

but it doesn't do anything. I have tried adding this in the functions.php file too:

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

That actually works, (the image will not display, but I'm not worried about that part). However, this seems sub optimal because I only want to extend the allowed mime types to include .tiff files, not just any type of file.

I've found a couple other solutions that rely on old/unmaintained plugins. I can't be using a plugin that isn't maintained!

Does anyone know how to get around this security feature?

Comment: WordPress already knows about the mime type for tiff files. They're allowed by default and there's not anything you need to do to add them at all. If you're getting that message, then probably something else on your system which is specifically disallowing them. Find out what that is, and turn it off.

Comment: Isn't the define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true); function call telling Wordpress to allow those types of file uploads though? Or is it doing something else that I'm not understanding (and not finding on google)?

Comment: Unfiltered upload will allow users with the Administrator role to upload whatever they like without restrictions, but by default, only administrator roles have that capability. Lesser users don't have that, even if you add that define.

Comment: So it must be overriding some server setting I take it? Interesting.

Comment: The combination of both code snippet worked for me.